# Symbol MC32N0 upgrade from CE 6.0 to WEC7: "Unsupported System Version"

Tags: c#, embedded, compact-framework, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I wrote a Compact Framework 2.0 C# application for a Symbol MC3xxx series barcode scanner mobile computer appliance thingy a handful of years ago.  At the time, the device was running CE 5.0.  Then the new one came and it ran CE 6.0, and things were still OK.  I was using and debugging with Visual Studio 2005 with no problems.

But now...After Motorola and then Zebra took over, I got a new device that we will be using called the MC32N0, but it runs Windows Embedded Compact 7.
Without going into the history of Microsoft's embedded device blunders through the years, I found that when we attempt to install our application, that we get an error message on the device that says "Unsupported System Version", that the application is too old for the OS on the device.

(side note, it is interesting that the "new" MC32N0 is running an OS that is already old, but there you go.)

How to get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MC32N0 requires the most recent version of the EMDK (2.9), MS upgrades to allow VS to run with Win CE 7.0, AND the platform file 32N0c70BenPS020000.exe from Zebra. You will correctly get an error message if you install your package without installing the latest symbol.all.arm.cab file because it is at a different hardware driver release level. You also will not be able to debug managed/native code using VS (2008 is what I used) if you don't install the platform file and compile your code directly for "Symbol MC3200c70" as the target device.

Comment: Jeez, getting the platform file from Zebra is painful, you have to register, they require loads of security, and then once you get through all that (in which their website froze twice on me), they say they'll have a Zebra rep get back to me within 24 hours. So waiting on the platform file to see if this does the trick, stand by...

Comment: Update: Zebra finally got back to me and gave me a temporary link to download the platform exe 32N0c70BenPS020000.exe.  I installed, and sure enough that did the trick, thanks @ggs.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a few things, and then some.

First thing I did was recompile everything on VS2008, using Compact Framework 3.5.  But I still got the error message, "Unsupported System Version".

After more research, I found that yes, Windows Embedded Compact 7 does indeed ship with CF 3.5, so I was good there, it had to be something else.

For this project I created an installer with a CAB file, so the application could get installed on the device.  In the project file for the CAB, in my case it was named "SmartDeviceCab1.vddproj", I opened that file using Notepad++, and found this:

```
    "Product"
    {
    "Name" = "8:Microsoft Visual Studio"
    "ProductName" = "8:Barcoding"
    "Manufacturer" = "8:DIS Corporation"
    "OSVersionMin" = "8:4.0"
    "OSVersionMax" = "8:6.99"
    "NoUninstall" = "11:FALSE"
    "Compress" = "11:FALSE"
    "CESetupDLL" = "8:"
    }
```

See the problem? OSVersionMax was set to 6.99, yet I was attempting to run on Compact 7.  So I changed the OSVersionMax to 7.01, and it worked!
The error message went away when I attempted to install the application.

Hope this helps other embedded barcode scanner developers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I recall having to do thi over the years as the OS levels rose.  Out of curiosity, what do you use to create CAB installs?  Looks like VS, do you use anything else too?

Comment: For this project I started with the VS2005 install project, and just upgraded this particular project to VS2008.  Unfortunately, I now cannot debug, but it doesn't really matter, the application is solid.  Meanwhile, I noticed MS brought back the installer project in VS2015, so very happy about that.